# Samsung RGB sensor api?

Tags: android, rgb, sensors

I am developing an app that is specific for the Samsung Galaxy S3 and this phone has a light sensor that can recognize separate values for red, green and blue. When you go to the phone app and enter *#0*# and click sensor, you can test this sensor. I want to use this feature in my app. Is there any API for this? I have searched but without any luck.

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169291/changing-led-color-for-notifications

Comment: That is the Notification LED, I am looking for the light sensor that detects colors.