# Android notification led, receive an event when it changes its status

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, led

I need to monitor the status of the notification LED on an android device. I've seen several post that explains how to customize the LED behavior (i.e. [Changing LED color for notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169291/changing-led-color-for-notifications)) however I would like to receive an event (using a receiver) whenever the LED changes its status or an app triggers a blink, regardless of which app caused the blink.

Is it possible to receive these event?
If yes, which intent filter should I use to receiver this kind of event?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to receive these event?

Definitely not in the Android SDK. A custom Android build packaged as a ROM mod may be able to determine this, at least for OS-triggered uses of the LED. System-level use of the LED (e.g., charging status) may not be visible to Android at all.