# Led notification preferences when battery is BATTERY_LOW?

Tags: android, radio-button, android-preferences, batterylevel

How can i create a simple radio button preferences to choose which led color use in BATTERY_LOW condition?

Answer (score 0):

To change the led color:
[Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169291/changing-led-color-for-notifications)

For the BATTERY_LOW you will need a `broadcastreceiver`:
[Check this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200721185308/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/getting-battery-information-on-android.html)

Ok.

First, create a file in the values folder. Call it something like "preference_res.xml". Then add the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string-array
    name="prefColor">
    <item>None</item>
    <item>Blue</item>
    <item>Green</item>
    <item>Yellow</item>
    <item>Other Color</item>
</string-array>
<string-array
    name="prefColorVal">
    <item>-1</item>
    <item>-2</item>
    <item>79</item>
    <item>24</item>
    <item>25</item>
    <item>27</item>
    <item>80</item>
</string-array>
 </resources>
```

(Be aware that the prefColorVal items should ref to the value you want the radio button to have. The values shown here are random.)

In your preference.xml, add something like this:

```
<ListPreference
    android:dialogTitle="Choose color"
    android:entries="@array/prefColor"
    android:entryValues="@array/prefColorVal"
    android:key="bat_below_15"
    android:negativeButtonText="Cancel"
    android:positiveButtonText="Save"
    android:summary="Choose color when below 15"
    android:title="Color when below 15" />
```

If you don't know how to get or use these values, here are some pointers, but you should google this stuff:

```
preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
```

and use this to get the value:

```
  preferences.getString("bat_below_15", Blue));
```

Comment: Well, i already have a broadcastreceiver..the problem are the radio buttons in the preferences. I want something like "show the color of led when the battery level is around 15%". And you can choose the color from a dialog with the radio buttons group..how can i do it?