# Cordova/Phonegap for Android using PushPlugin change LED Color of Notification

Tags: android, cordova, notifications

Is there a way to change the color of the phone-led (status-led) from (current) white to green? So when GCM sends a notification to the device the led should light up in green.

I am using Cordova 5.3.3 and the PushPlugin at `github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push`.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin does not have native support for that.  You will have to change the plugin code to support this feature.  This feature is also highly phone model / brand dependent.  See Stuti's answer in this thread for some example code.

[Changing LED color for notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169291/changing-led-color-for-notifications)

You would make the above changes to the plugin Android source directory.

The other option is to include the local notifications plugin in addition to the push notification plugin.  This local notification plugin has a simple interface to change the LED blink color (if the hardware supports it).  When you receive your push notification, you would then call the local notification plugin to change the LED color.  Documentation on this plugin is here:

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/04.-Scheduling

Answer (score 0):

This can with current version be done by changing the payload on the server.
From https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#led-in-notifications

```
{
  "data": {
    "title": "Green LED",
    "message": "This is my message with a Green LED",
    "ledColor": [0, 0, 255, 0]
  }
}
```

Where the arguments are A, R, G, B